# How to make all future dates non-clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to disable all future dates in the calendar after today. Today's date is highlighted in Yellow (`Feb 23rd 2012`)in the diagram below. All the other future dates should be non clickable. How can i do that ?

For instance 24th,25th.... etc should not be clickable

[image]

Note:
           `$('.datepicker').BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), DateTime.MaxValue));` doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JQuery UI datepicker calandar, use `maxdate` method : http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ maxDate: new Date() });
```

`new Date()` corresponds to the current date

**demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/21/

Comment: I have added a fiddler demo link

Answer (score 0):

if the datepicker wizard has already been initialized on the input, you can also use:

```
    $( ".selector" ).datepicker("option", {maxDate: "+0D" });
```

That should also work when a day ends and a new day starts *after* the datepicker has been initialized.